# How to search and replace a content of a file using shell script?

Tags: shell

I have started learning shell scripting a few days ago. My scenario is, i have to search and replace a content which exists in different lines in a file using shell script.

For Example, I have mentioned the path name in a file :-

```
path = /home/test/db
```

My name is so and

```
path = /home/test/db
```

Here,
      The path name  "/home" has to be replaced with "/Second" in specified lines of the file using shell script. By using "sed" command i have tried and replaced the content of the file has only one line but i am struggling with replacing which is present in different lines. I am using "If" condition in shell script.Please do help me in resolving this case.

Thanks and Regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you missed the g option in your sed command. See below

```
sed "s/find/replace/g" filename
```

Comment: s stands for substitute command to sed and g stands for global which means to substitute all occurences of the text matching the regular expression indicated by the `find` by the text indicated by `replace`

Comment: Thanks for your precious reply will try and update. Once again thanks.

Comment: As the find and replace portions appear to be paths, using a different delimiter will likely be helpful: `sed 's!/path/one!/path/two!g`

Comment: Hi @Vikas Nalwar, Works fine. Your help is really appreciated. Once again thanks.

Comment: Hi @Vikas Nalwar, For example: sed "s/raj/ravi/g" here ravi is placed in another file. The reason behind, i am getting the word as an input using "read word" and writing the word to another file. So i want to read the word "ravi" from other file and replaced to another file. Please help me on this.Please provide me the example

Comment: You can't do it in simple one liner command. You can read the replace expression from whereever you want and store it in a variable and use the value of the variable in the sed command. Below is an example:  sed "s/find/$variable/g".

Comment: Hi @Vikas Nalwar, I had tried this but it does-not works. Finally i have acquired the simple liner command. Anyway Thanks for your valuable Suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

**sed -i 's/original/new/g' file.txt**

Explanation:

> **sed** = Stream EDitor
>   **-i** = in-place (i.e. save back to the original file) The command string:
>
> **s** = the substitute command
>
> **original** = a regular expression describing the word to replace (or just the word itself)
>
> **new** = the text to replace it with
>
> **g** = global (i.e. replace all and not just the first occurrence)
>
> **file.txt** = the file name

Answer (score 0):

The below mentioned code will search all JS files under "search_folder_name". It will find "version_number" for all occurrences in the defined folder and replace it with respective value defined. Save the below menioned code in .sh file say, test.sh

```js
#!/bin/bash
versionNo=0.0.1
find ./search_folder_name/ -name \*.js -type f -print0 | while read -d $'\0' file; do
    echo "Processing $file"
    sed -i '' 's/{version_number}/'$versionNo'/g' $file
done
```